# Run two Url with two thread name in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want each thread run an Url different.

I write code like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RegisterLink))
    {
        Name = "Thread1"
    };
    t1.Start();

    var t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RegisterLink))
    {
        Name = "Thread2"
    };
    t2.Start();
    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
}
static bool start_Link()
{
    int idx = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Replace("Thread", "")) - 1;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtLink.Rows)
        {
            link[idx] = dtRow["get_link"].ToString();
            browser_array[idx].DeleteAllCookies();
            browser_array[idx].GoToUrl(link[idx]);
        }
    }
}

static void RegisterLink()
{
    int idx = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name.Replace("Thread", "")) - 1;
    try
    {
        switch (stepRun[idx])
        {
            case 0:
                start_new();
                break;
            case 1:
                compare();
                break;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ExitALL();
        return;
    }
}
```

The `dtLink` is DataTable contains all link.

Example: I have two link { 0: google.com, 1: reddit.com }. It only open link 1 is reddit.com.

I have many hard time to try debug when using Thread.

Comment: Could you clarify your loops? You are never using the dc variable. Just test your code for one Thread before using more.

Comment: I updated my question. I forget to delete code not necessary.

Comment: You never increment `idx` so the same object `browser_array[idx]` is used for each row.

Comment: `idx` is `ThreadName`. It will increment. So it can create two object browser_array[0 -> 1] when I start two thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments into a thread by using an object[].

eg.

```
static bool start_link(object data)
{
     object [] arguments = data as object[];
     int idx = (int) arguments[0];
}


Thread t1 = new Thread(start_link) { Name = "Thread 1"};
t1.Start(new object[]{ 0 });
```

Comment: Sorry. I call `start_link` from `RegisterLink()`. Must I change the code like to work? Please see my update question.